# Могут ли определения, которые должны были бы обособляться, парцеллироваться?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, приложение, определения

**У старших братьев была куча обязанностей по дому. Выносить мусор, протирать пыль и пылесосить, выгуливать собаку и множество других дел и работ.**

- Необходимость в том, чтобы предложения были недлинные (особенно если учесть, что после "старших братьев" м.б. обособленные тире приложения *Вани, Пети, Миши, Димы*). Возможна ли здесь парцелляция?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возможна. Парцеллировать в данном случае лучше точками, а не запятыми.

*У старших братьев была куча обязанностей по дому. Выносить мусор. Вытирать пыль и пылесосить. Выгуливать собаку. И множество других дел и забот.*